# When spying GUI objects with squish, Different GUI namespaces are displayed (uiAutomation vs Wpf) depending on the connection type (LAN vs WIFI)

Tags: network-programming, ethernet, squish

So I'm using Squish 7.1.0 and when running some scripts remotely they don't work when i'm connected through ethernet but they do through wifi (I am trying to migrate to using only ethernet).

I went to save the object map for both configurations and I got a different namespace for each connection type. LAN got UIAutomation and WIfi got WPF, the problem is that all my objects are based on the WPF representation of those objects.

What I can see on wifi: `<element id="18a4db736e3" class="Image" namespace="Wpf">`

What I can see on LAN: `<element id="18a4da11807" class="Image" namespace="UIAutomation">`

Comment: I do not recall any cases where the network connection ever played a role, nor how it could play a role for Squish's GUI object identification, therefore I recommend that you contact the vendor's support to discuss the case with them. (It is problematic that you paraphrase what you are doing, such as "I went to export the object type", because even to me - as a long term user of Squish - it is not clear what this means specifically, and what steps this consists of.)

Comment: My bad I meant I saved the object map, i'll change it in the og post. I am starting to think it might be a windows security setting since I am using a work laptop.

Comment: I think you need to contact the vendor, to analyze what Squish can log about its UI Automation and .NET support in the failing case. Having .NET support not kick in based on type of network connection is odd, but as long as it is reproducible there is usually something to analyze.

Comment: I know to be able to see wpf objects squish 'injects' a hook into the application. So maybe some firewall rule could be blocking that?

Answer (score 0):

Firewall seems unrelated to such process operations. Are perhaps network drives involved, where the different network interface type could possibly play a role? But anyway, I recommend contacting the vendor.